# Select list value not selecting and pass to the AngularJS function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying post data of textbox and select List to the AngularJS JavaScript function.I use the ng-repeat to load data in to select list. Data is loading but value not selecting and pass to the AngularJS function. Can anyone help to figure out this issue

AngularJS code

```
var app = angular.module('projectmdl', []);
app.controller('projectcontroller', function ($scope, projectservice) {
 GetCustomer();
function GetCustomer() {
        projectservice.GetCustomerDetails().then(function (d) {
            $scope.customers = d.data;
        }, function () {
            alert("Error Loading Customer Details");
        });
    }



$scope.saveproject = function () {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to insert ?")
    if (r == true) {
        if ($scope.Action == 'Add') {
            projectservice.AddProjectDetails($scope.project).then(function (d) {
                LoadProjects();
                var custcode = $scope.pr_custcode;
                $scope.msg = 'Insert Successfully';
                $scope.project = null;
                $scope.pr_code = '';
                $scope.pr_name = '';
                $scope.pr_description = '';
            }, function () {
                LoadProjects();
            });
        }
    }
    else {

        LoadProjects();
    }
}

})
.service('projectservice', function ($http) {
    this.GetCustomerDetails = function () {
        var response = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Admin/CustomerDetails',
            datatype:'json'
        });
        return response;
    }
});
```

HTML code.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Project Code</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" ng-model="project.pr_code" name="required" id="required">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Project Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="project.pr_name" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Description</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="project.pr_description" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Customer</label>
        <div class="controls">

          @*<select style="width:210px;" name="pr_custcode" id="pr_custcode" ng-model="project.pr_custcode">                                         
            <option ng-repeat="cu in customers" value="{{cu.cus_code}}" >{{cu.cus_name}}</option>
          </select>
          <tt>{{project.pr_custcode}}</tt>*@
          <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="project.singleSelect">
            <option ng-repeat="pr in customers" value="{{pr.cus_code}}">{{pr.cus_name}}</option>
          </select><br>
          <tt>singleSelect = {{project.singleSelect}}</tt>                                    
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="saveproject()" class="btn btn-success">
          <input type="submit" value="Clear" ng-click="clearproject()" class="btn btn-success" />
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="control-group">
         <div class="controls">
           <p style="color:green">{{msg}}</p>
         </div>
         </div>
         @*<div class="form-actions">
         </div>*@</form>
```

ASP MVC Code

```
[HttpPost]
        public string AddProjects(Project projects) {
            if (projects != null)
            {
                te.Projects.Add(projects);
                te.SaveChanges();
                return "Project Add Successfully";
            }
            else {
                return "Error";
            }

        }
```

Comment: where are you passing the value?

Comment: I am passing form data to (ng-click="saveproject()") to angular js $scope.saveproject() function and to asp mvc method (AddProjects). but select list data is not passing others are coming@Sajeetharan

Comment: Where is `AddProjects` call from client-side ?

Comment: AddProject call  this.AddProjectDetails = function (projects) {

        var response = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Admin/AddProjects',
            data: projects,
            datatype:'json'

        });
        return response;
    }

Comment: I have Edit the AddProject angular code in my post see @Alexandru-IonutMihai